# What about the way photon's bounce of a surface causes a human to interpret an image?

Tags: photons

I have read online that we interpret an image based on photons entering our eyes and some technical stuff. But I am still unclear about how photons bouncing on different surfaces can be so different from one another as to cause a human to see different things.

**Could someone explain how exactly data (photons) can produce different images so to speak.**

Comment: They bounce in different directions: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of an image as a collection of points with a location and a colour (much like pixels). A photon that enters the eye has a specific origin (it comes from a specific location) and wavelength. The origin determines how it enters the eye, and the wavelength determines which "colour detector" is activated in the eye.

If you have many photons entering your eye, they project an image through the lense of the eye and onto the detector mechanism in the back of the eye. Photons coming from different directions activate different parts of this mechanism, and the same happens for photons of different wavelength. This information is converted into an electrical signal which enters your brain, where your mind interprets it into an image.

Comment: If this is true would it not be possible to have say a kind of projector in front of you with image rec soft to know where exactly your eye is and then shoot photons into the eye to create some predefined image in front of you? Basically creating a hologram.

Comment: Yes. This is almost what a virtual reality headset does (except for the eye tracking).